# Hibernate returns null for time '00:00:00'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using spring hibernate for a web application. It has a `OpenHours` modal which return the open time. It has a field `sundayOpen` `type="time"`. Whenever the time in database column '*sundayOpen*' is equal to '00:00:00' the `sundayOpen` is returning `null`. But all the other times it returns the correct time. 
I have experienced this issue with hibernate 5.4.2 and 3.6.0.

Is there any way to get '00:00:00' instead of `null`?

OpenHours.hbm.xml

```
<class name="com.example.OpenHours" table="openHours" schema="abxd_db">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id"/>
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id> 
        <property name="sundayOpen" type="time">
            <column length="16" name="sundayOpen"/>
        </property>
</class>
```

OpenHours.java

```
 public class OpenHours implements Serializable {

    private long id;
     private Time sundayOpen; 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Time getSundayOpen() {
        return sundayOpen;
    }

    public void setSundayOpen(Time sundayOpen) {
        this.sundayOpen = sundayOpen;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom [`UserType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html#types-custom-ut),

```
public class CustomTimeUserType implements UserType {
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement ps, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null)
            ps.setString(index, "00:00:00");
        else
            ps.setDate(index, (Time) value);
    }
   // implement other methods

}
```

And use it in property,

```
<property name="sundayOpen" type="time">
    <column length="16" name="com.pkg.CustomTimeUserType"/>
</property>
```

I am not sure but you can also try with `zeroDateTimeBehavior`,

```
hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior=round
```

Comment: Thanks ! I found my error after your answer, I had `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` in my connection string. I changed it to `zeroDateTimeBehavior=round`. now it works fine ! !